# How to use a void method in a Java Reactor chain?

Tags: java, java-8, project-reactor

Consider this code:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono.just(1)
            .map(Main::return_int) // is ok
//          .map(Main::return_void) // is not ok
            .subscribe();
    }

    private static void return_void(int input) {
        // do stuff with input
    }

    private static int return_int(int input) {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Obviously it's forbidden to use `Mono#map` with a void param, I get `error: method map in class Mono<T> cannot be applied to given types; (...)`

Now how can I call this method `return_void()` in a chain ?

Should I use another operator than `#map`? Or is there no other choice than wrapping `return_void()` into a method that returns `Mono< Void>` ?

Comment: that really shall depend on what you wnat to in that void function. If its stateless `map(a -> {return_void(); return a;})` should do it ideally.

Comment: @Naman In my case it will be used to throw an exception in case of invalid input. About your example, I find it cumbersome to return the input if I don't need it in the rest of chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `Mono#doOnNext` that does not transform the flow, but allows you to perform side effects (something that returns `void`, as in your case)

Also, consider using `Mono#handle` to either proceed or call `sink.error(...)` when the value does not satisfy your condition instead of throwing from your `void` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The community seems to discourage the use of `Mono#doOnNext` in other cases than logging. You don't agree ?

Comment: `doOnNext` is the operator for side effects that should not affect the flow (and the only way to affect is to throw an exception). 
If you need to return an error, see the second part of my answer about `Mono#handle`.

Comment: Just to add a note: a Mono operator must return Mono<>, if it returns void it simply cannot be used in a Mono stream.

Comment: Could you provide a simple code example or a link that suits my case, using `Mono#handle` or `sink()` ? I'm having a hard time finding such code on the web.